# Why $ (A\vec{x})'A \vec{x} = \vec{0}$ implies that $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is a symmetric matrix. And $\vec{x} \neq \vec{0} $ where $\vec{x} \in Nul(A^2) $

Since A is symmetric we know that this relation holds: $A^T = A$

So $A^2 = A^TA = AA$

And $ Nul(A^2) = Nul(A) $

I've seen the following argumentation, and I'm wondering what are the intermediary steps between (1) and (2), in other words why exactly the relation (1) implies relation (2)?

$
\begin{align}
\vec{0} & = A^2 \vec{x}  \\ 
 & = (A'A\vec{x})\qquad  \qquad \qquad\\ \end{align}$

We are to show that $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ holds.

$
\begin{align}
\vec{0} & = \vec{x^T} A^TA \vec{x}  \\ 
 & = (A\vec{x})^T A \vec{x} \qquad  (1)\qquad\Rightarrow  A\vec{x} = \vec{0} \qquad(2)\\ \end{align}$

Comment: The argument as written is incorrect. It is true that if $x^TA^TAx=0$ then $Ax=0$, but it is *not* true that $x^TA^TAx=Ax$. (Nor that $A^TAx=x^TA^TAx$, as written in the immediately previous line.)

Comment: You still have $A^TAx=x^TA^TAx$, which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is a scalar, while $\vec{0}$ is a vector... So it's not really equal.

However, $\vec x^\top \vec 0=0$, obviously. And $\vec 0=A^2\vec x=A^\top A\vec x$, so $\vec x A^\top A\vec x=\|A\vec x\|_{fro}^2=0$, where $\|\cdot\|_{fro}$ is the frobenius norm.

Since $\|A\vec x\|_{fro}^2=0$, $A\vec x$ must be $\vec 0$.

Comment: Thanks, updated the initial post to be more accurate.
Yeah, it makes perfectly sense now. So in words, if the norm of a vector equals zero, the vector itself would be the zero-vector, because any other vector has a length different to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Note that $(Ax)^T=x^TA^T$ . So, $x^TA^TAx=(Ax)^TAx$

Comment: That relation I am fully aware of, however I'm wondering about why the last step reduces to Ax.
We are to show that Ax = 0, if it where the other way around (which is the opposite of what is beeing asked for) I'd guess since Ax = 0, then (Ax)' = 0' = 0

Comment: But that wouldn't serve as a sufficient argumentation here, cause we are to show that Ax = 0, so we can't assume it is so before we have proven it is so, am I thinking right about this?

Comment: $Ax$ is a vector. The scalar product with itself is zero. So, $Ax$ itself must be zero.